# Progress column with text in ObjectListView

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I have a table (ObjectListView) with audio records in rows.
One of it's columns -  Length in format hh:mm:ss
I have to apply BarRenderer to this column to display play progress in this column (both progress and length).
Shoud I write own Renderer or it is possible to use any existing one?

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved this using a custom class derived from BarRenderer. Consider the overridden Render method.

```
public class BarTextRenderer : BarRenderer
{
    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Make a BarTextRenderer
    /// </summary>
    public BarTextRenderer() : base() {}

    /// <summary>
    /// Make a BarTextRenderer for the given range of data values
    /// </summary>
    public BarTextRenderer (int minimum, int maximum) : base(minimum, maximum) { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Make a BarTextRenderer using a custom bar scheme
    /// </summary>
    public BarTextRenderer (Pen pen, Brush brush) : base(pen, brush) { }
    /// <summary>
    /// Make a BarTextRenderer using a custom bar scheme
    /// </summary>
    public BarTextRenderer (int minimum, int maximum, Pen pen, Brush brush) : base(minimum, maximum, pen, brush) { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Make a BarTextRenderer that uses a horizontal gradient
    /// </summary>
    public BarTextRenderer (Pen pen, Color start, Color end) : base(pen, start, end) { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Make a BarTextRenderer that uses a horizontal gradient
    /// </summary>
    public BarTextRenderer (int minimum, int maximum, Pen pen, Color start, Color end) : base(minimum, maximum, pen, start, end) { }

    #endregion

  public override void Render(Graphics g, Rectangle r)
  {
    base.Render(g, r);
    float x = r.X + (float)r.Width / 2f;
    float w = r.Width/2f;
    float h = Math.Max (r.Height-this.Font.Size, 0.8f*r.Height);
    float y = (float)r.Y + 0.6f*(r.Height-h);

    RectangleF rf = new RectangleF(x, y, w, h);
    g.DrawString(this.Aspect.ToString(), this.Font, this.Brush, rf);
  }
}
```